# contra -- is this a preposition?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Usage example with a [context](http://www.businessinsider.com/russia-is-on-a-holy-mission-and-the-west-doesnt-get-it-2015-1):

> “Every one of these sentences is, to put it mildly, a stretch,” explained one seasoned Kremlin-watcher, and the news this week from Ukraine has been grim, **contra** Obama’s hopeful pose. While Russia’s economy remains seriously hurt from sanctions and, even more, the sharp drop in oil prices, the notion that this is taming Putin’s baser urges is not only untrue, it’s more likely the opposite of the truth, as I cautioned a month ago.

Is that a preposition? Something similar to the preposition *contrary to*? I've never seen this one before plus many English dictionaries out there don't even have it listed as a preposition.

Comment: I've never seen it before either, but based on the context, I would read it as *contrary to*, just as you suggested.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contra

Comment: It's best to allow at least 24 hours for responses before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. More info is [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to The free dictionary, contra can be used as a prefix, noun, preposition, or adverb.

I think the contra used in the sentence is a preposition to mean in contrast to, against, or contrary to, as you understand. However, if used as a preposition, I don't think it's appropriate to put a comma before "contra". An example of its use as a preposition is mentioned in a dictionary as follows:

CONSIDER THE PROBLEMS OF THE TEENAGER CONTRA THOSE OF THE ADULT.

Comment: Actually, it's fine to have a comma before _contra_ when using it as a preposition. It would be wrong to leave it out in the quoted paragraph.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contra

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, it is short form for contrary to. In this instance it is being used as a preposition.

Comment: No, it's not slang. It's actually a preposition thefreedictionary.com/contra also http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/contra

Comment: @colleeen in fact it is short form, it says so on the link you posted.

Comment: @TrevorClarke It says that the word "contra", in the sense of [a revolutionary who attempted to overthrow the government of Nicaragua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contras) in the 1980s, originated as a short form of _contrarrevolucionario._ The word _contra_ in the sense that the OP asked about is not a short form. It's the Latin word _contra,_ imported directly into English.

Comment: It's definitely not a short form of "contrary to". The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/40310) quotes English usage at least as far back as 1480, usually paired in a phrase with the Latin word _pro_ ("_pro_ and _contra_"). The word has moved into general usage from specialized usage in philosophy and law.

Comment: Please look at the link in the first comment it clearly states that it is short form.

Comment: Trevor - I took a look, as you suggested, and I think @Ben is right. The link reads "**contra** (1) *preposition* against". That's it. There's nothing about a shortened form until you scroll further down the page to **contra (2)**. But those numbers show that we are talking about [two different words](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/wind) that happen to have the same spelling, much like **wind** (as in, _the wind blows from the north_) and **wind** (as in, _remember to wind the clock tonight before bed_).